# ROS Odometry message: what are the source and target frames of the pose?

Tags: ros

The [ROS odometry message](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) contais a pose and a twist.

The twist is described in the `child_frame_id`. What are the source and target frames of the pose? I assume that the pose is meant to transform between the `header.frame_id` and the `child_frame_id` (which does not necessarily need to be base_link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a clear definition to answer the question. However, if the pose was defined between the `header.frame_id` and `base_link`, the message could be split into two messages (pose and twist). To make sense of having both pose and twist in the message, I think that the pose shall be interpreted between the `header.frame_id` and the `child_frame_id` of the message.

It even seems that it's wanted to be undefined. The popular [robot-localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/728) package is about to interpret the message depending on the current situtation. For `sensor_msgs/Imu` messages, a similar case is true, as the navsat_transform node and the ekf/ukf nodes interpret the `header.frame_id` completely different.

Update: An ongoing [pull request](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/728) leaves the answer of this particular question to the user who will be able to decide based on a parameter.